# Uploading file of 1 gb using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my application developed in asp.net, client wants to upload files of 1 GB. please tell me some trick how i can achieve it through it.

this application is about to watching video online so the administrator will upload the movies videos file. so now how i can upload files which are large than 1 Gb

Comment: Why do you want to use jquery or javascript? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What exactly is different from uploading a 1 gb file instead of a 1 mb file, except your system limits may block the process and it takes lot longer? I just don't see how the size of the filesize would require some extra "tricks". You may want to add some progress bars to display how much has been uploaded, but that is irrelevant to the functionality of the page.

Comment: this application is about to watching video online so the administrator will upload the movies videos file. so now how i can upload files which are large than 1 Gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.uploadify.com](http://www.uploadify.com)

Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that integrates a fully-customizable multiple file upload utility on your website. It uses a mixture of Javascript, ActionScript, and any server-side language to dynamically create an instance over any DOM element on a page.